# Remove an attribute from all the rows of JSON object using jquery?

Tags: javascript, arrays, properties

Any idea how to remove an attribute in all the rows of JSON object using Jquery?

Eg:

```
[{name: "Moroni", age: 50, role: 'Administrator'},
  {name: "Tiancum", age: 43, role: 'Administrator'},
  {name: "Enos", age: 34, role: 'User'}];
```

to

```
[{name: "Moroni", role: 'Administrator'},
  {name: "Tiancum", role: 'Administrator'},
  {name: "Enos", role: 'User'}];
```

So the `age` attribute is removed from all the rows.

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: So welcome to programming. You want to "remove an attribute" (you should call it by its correct name, which is "property"). Do you know how to do that? If not, please research it. (Hint: it's `delete`.) Next, you want to do something to "all the rows". I guess that means you want to "iterate" over the "rows" (which you should call "elements"). Do you know how to iterate over the elements of an array? If not, please research that. (Hint: you could use a `for` loop.) Finally, please call this a "JavaScript object", not a "JSON object". JSON has a specific meaning, a format for data interchange.

Comment: By the way, "Teancum" is the correct spelling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to iterate through all the elements of an array, and delete age property.

```
var arr = [{name: "Moroni", age: 50, role: 'Administrator'},
    {name: "Tiancum", age: 43, role: 'Administrator'},
    {name: "Enos", age: 34, role: 'User'}];
for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
    delete arr[i].age;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/bruceyang/21q9g16z/)

Answer (score 0):

In any linux shell:
sed 's/age: [0-9]*(, ){0,1}//' SRC_FILE >DST_FILE